# How to use notes2bib package on Overleaf

Tags: footnotes, overleaf, notes, notes2bib

I want to move all the footnotes from all chapters of my Overleaf document over to the References section (instead of at the end of each chapter), in a separate "Footnotes" part.

I have found notes2bib for that purpose but I haven't been able to make it work.

Can someone please guide me through the steps of using notes2bib on Overleaf? I looked into its documentation but haven't had much success, bit of a noob here :').

Any help appreciated! Thanks

> edit in reply to your comments @Mensch, @David Carlisle

So far I have uploaded the notes2bib.dtx file from the downloaded zip folder from CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib?lang=en) into my preamble .tex file, and so far it seems I can use the command \bibnote and my notes are included in the "References" section generated at the end of the document. However I have the following 2 issues:

1. They appear *in* the "References" section where the citations (\cite) are, and I would like to have a separate "Notes" Section. How do I get this?
2. They appear in a random order within the references, and instead of their individual numbering, there is a ", ," mark.

It would really help me a lot if you could point out the exact steps I should take in order to use notes2bib.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: it's  a latex package, and in texlive what do you need that is specific to overleaf?

Comment: @Mensch I have updated my initial post with more context, please take a look above! thanks for your time and any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: What we need to know is how your document is set up. Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you are doing? It is unclear to me whether you really mean and where you got stuck.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry but I have limited experience with overleaf and am not well-versed in the technical aspects of the platform. In my understanding and from what I read, since notes2bib is in texlive, shouldn't it automatically pop up as an option when I use \usepackage ? In my case it didn't. 
In any case, if you could point me the exact process I should follow in order to be able to install and use the notes2bib package in my overleaf document, I'd be grateful!

Comment: As for the term "Overleaf": Overleaf is just an online editor that helps you with typing documents that can be compiled with (La)TeX. If you press "Recompile" in Overleaf, PDFLaTeX will normally be started (or XeLaTeX or whatever comiler you choose). What Overleaf tells you inside the editor window is just a rough guess about what you are doing. You should be able to type `\usepackage{notes2bib}` and this would work, because under the hood, Overleaf has a full TeX installation available of which this package is a part. In short: Your problem is most likely a (La)TeX, not an Overleaf problem.

Comment: no the completion helps with a few common packagages but normally on overleaf you would do the same as on a local system and just type `\usepackage{somepackage}` to use the package. If you show what you did and what error you got someone could help

Comment: @JasperHabicht thanks for the tip! I'm working on understanding how to provide a MWE from the link you sent. Just to clarify, I am using footnotes in my document, and I just want to put all my footnotes in the end of the document ( as a separate section before the bibliography) instead of at the end of the chapter

Comment: "So far I have uploaded the notes2bib.dtx file from the downloaded zip folder from CTAN " No! don't do that. Overleaf has a full texlive so has that package already installed, you almost never need to get sources from ctan for anything,

Comment: are you sure you want notes2bib (rather than say endnotes package) but for notes2bib make a small example in your question following https://texdoc.org/serve/notes.bib/0 and say how it is not working, someone will help....

Comment: thank you all for your help, I eventually managed to achieve what I wanted by using endnotes!